# jquery ajax loads list of results even there's nothing to query

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

So I am learning from a tutorial for jquery and ajax and till now I have a search form for searching and returning the search results. And it works fine. But when I delete the words from the form or backspace the words, it loads all the status in the list. What do I do to return only when there is some word and to return nothing if there's no word in the form.

snippet of status.html:

```
{% block add_account %}
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" />

<ul id="search-results">

</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

ajax.js:

```
$(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/status/search_status/",
            data: {
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data)
}
```

ajax.html:

```
{% if statuss.count > 0 %}

{% for status in statuss %}
    <li><a href="/status/get/{{status.id}}/">{{status.status}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}

<p>None to show</p>

{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def search_status(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text=''

    statuss = Status.objects.filter(status__icontains = search_text)

    return render(request, 'ajax_search.html', {'statuss':statuss})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    if (!$.trim(this.value).length) return; //<< returns from here if nothing to search
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/status/search_status/",
        data: {
            'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
```

BTW, you should throttle your request on keyup to avoid multiple call if user is typing too fast:

```
(function () {
    var throttleTimer;
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
        throttleTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$.trim(this.value).length) return;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/status/search_status/",
                data: {
                    'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: searchSuccess,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        }, 100);
    });
}());
```

Comment: @Robin returns anything? What do you mean? Request should be send if there is something to search

Comment: I am sorry the firs script that you gave didn't return anything, i mean nothing. But the second one works. But still, when I backspace in the form, it still displays the last query in the list... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Robin instead of keyup, try using keypress. And for the first script, must work, so you are doing something wrong somewhere. Always check your console for typo

Comment: keypress returns nothing. I just copied and paste the script that you gave me.

Comment: Can it be because of the jquery version?

Comment: @Robin No, there is no reason here except if you are using a very old jq version.

Comment: Or is there any way to tell #search-result not to load if there's no keyword in the form?

Comment: "no keyword in the form" You mean no value in search field?! This is why i posted answer... If not working for you, you are doing something wrong but i cannot devine it, sorry...