# How do I jQuery ajax live search for the models in Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

I tried live search with jquery and ajax, and even posted a question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736864/jquery-ajax-loads-list-of-results-even-theres-nothing-to-query), but there seems to have some serious problem somewhere in my view or in the ajax script I wrote. It searches and loads the content correctly.

But if I backspace and there's no value in the search form, it still shows me a list of value that I entered the first time. I think there's really a big problem in my code.

models.py:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like")
```

snippet of the .html:

```
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
        <ul id="search-results">
        </ul>
```

views.py:

```
def search_status(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        search_text = request.GET['search_text']
        if search_text is not None and search_text != u"":
            search_text = request.GET['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''  # I even tried using 0

    statuss = Status.objects.filter(status__contains = search_text)

    return render(request, 'ajax_search.html', {'statuss':statuss})
```

I have already loaded the jquery.min.js script in my template.

Comment: 1. Please show us the view. The model is irrelevant for the case here. 2. In your browser, check javascript's console and confirm there are no errors on javascript. ;-)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão In the console, it shows no errors. I have edited and have added the view that I used. Please check it. Do you want the js script too?Thanks.

Comment: ok, good. Can you try put stattuss inside the if, and in the else just put statuss = []?

Comment: I tried putting the statuss inside the second if and in the else I put the statuss =[], but even now its showing me the first entered letter.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão I think this is the problem. Suppose I have entered `check`. Now in the console, when I backspace once, it queries for `chec` and once again backspace, it queries for `che` and so on. And then when on the last backspace, it stops at querying for letter `c`. It queries for the firs entered word even if there's no value in the search form, and returns anything that match with letter c.

Comment: ok. Then I think you need to show the relevante js, to see why it is always sending the last word, even after you erased it.

Comment: Ok I got it. I don't know how. But after I indented the else statement and the return statement it worked! Thank you so much though for bearing with me!

Comment: Please, post the solution for your question, and then accept it. ;)

Answer (score 10):

I had to indent the else statement and the return statement in the views.py. And also to put `statuss` in the second if statement. And then it worked as I expected! Please guide me if there's any improvements to make. Thank you!

views.py:

```
def search_status(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        search_text = request.GET['search_text']
        if search_text is not None and search_text != u"":
            search_text = request.GET['search_text']
            statuss = Status.objects.filter(status__contains = search_text)
        else:
            statuss = []

        return render(request, 'ajax_search.html', {'statuss':statuss})
```

This was the ajax script:

```
$(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/status/search_status/",
            data: {
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data)
}
```

Snippet of index.html:

```
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
    <ul id="search-results">
    </ul>
```

The included html:

```
{% if statuss > 0 %}
    <ul class="statuss">
        {% for status in statuss %}
            <li>
                <p>{{status}}</p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}    
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No status found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What was the content of 'ajax_search.html' ?